# Ajax in Wicket Panel doesn't work

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have some panels with one text field on my page. I'd like to add ajax behavior to all my text fields but it works only for the first text field - only when I change the first text field the ajax request is sending.

They must be panels because I'd like to improve these adding another components.

Hear is my code.

```
public class TestPage extends WebPage {

    private BigDecimal test1 = new BigDecimal("1");
    private BigDecimal test2 = new BigDecimal("2");
    private BigDecimal test3 = new BigDecimal("3");
    private BigDecimal test4 = new BigDecimal("4");

    public TestPage() {
        Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form");
        add(form);

        form.add(new TestPanel("test1", test1));
        form.add(new TestPanel("test2", test2));
        form.add(new TestPanel("test3", test3));
        form.add(new TestPanel("test4", test4));
    }

    private class TestPanel extends Panel {
        private BigDecimal amount;

        private TestPanel(String id, BigDecimal amount) {
            super(id);
            this.amount = amount;

            TextField<BigDecimal> = new TextField<BigDecimal>("amount", new PropertyModel<BigDecimal>(this, "amount"));
            add(textField);
            textField.add(new TestBehavior());
            textField.setRequired(true);
        }
    }

    public class TestBehavior extends OnChangeAjaxBehavior {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            //this text is pirinting only when I change the first text field
            System.out.println("---------- TestBehavior.onUpdate() ----------------");
        }
    }
}
```

TestPage.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
    <form wicket:id="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <span wicket:id="test1"></span>
        <span wicket:id="test2"></span>
        <span wicket:id="test3"></span>
        <span wicket:id="test4"></span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

TestPage$TestPanel.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <input wicket:id="amount" id="amount" type="text" class="input-small"/>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer but: 1) i would send to the `TestPanel`s `PropertyModel`, not the `BigDecimal`s you send. 2) I would first add `TestPanel`s to the form, then add the form 3) Put `TestPanel` in a seperate file for clearer code.

Comment: Remove the `id="amount"` from the input. On the TextField do `.setOutputMarkupId(true)`

Comment: "Remove the id="amount" from the input" - this solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `id="amount"` from the `<input>`. Instead set on the `TextField` `.setOutputMarkupId(true);`